while embedding apache superset 3.1.1 with my angular 15 application i am getting unexpected metrics error and guest user cant modify chart payload
[getting metrics error](https://i.sstatic.net/yI[unable to load charts](https://i.sstatic.net/XFLct.png)908.png)
I tried downgrading version from 3.1.1 to 3.1.0, but did not work facing same issue and have set HTTP_HEADERS = {'X-Frame-Options': 'ALLOWALL'}, added . But nothing works. Tired SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE="None".

after downloading 4.0.0 version fixed my issue
